# How do I change back my projects names in Eclipse from naming their main?

Tags: eclipse, class, project, program-entry-point

I installed the newer Eclipse v21.0.1 and started importing some android projects when I noticed its naming off all the projects by their Main class?? For example, if I was importing a project that has MainActivity.java its trying to name the project MainActivity. I'm so confused because this has never happened, and I looked in all the settings and questions on here but its too general of a topic so everything isn't relevant to what I'm looking for. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was trying to import them as android projects. Now I imported them as general projects and their names checked out fine. :)